# How can I make an accordion control in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, accordion

How can I find or make an accordion control in ASP.NET?

Comment: You have to be very careful. Those accordions can get pretty loud and you wouldn't want to wake up your napping coworkers.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use the AJAX control?

Comment: You find one by asking on stack overflow (or did you mean "where"?).

How to roll your own is a lot more complex a question as there are a lot of different ways to do this sort of thing but assuming you want a smooth experience then its javascript to manipulate stuff and right here, right now, jQuery would be a good way to go.

Answer (score 5):

http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/Accordion/Accordion.aspx

Answer (score 4):

I would prefer using [one from jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/). Why you need to reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 0):

Here is quite good described it
http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=215&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1